# issue using access privileges

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have two view controllers and nibs. I populated one view controller with a toggle switch and declared this in its header file:

```
@public UISwitch *toggleSwitch;
```

and exposed it as a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *toggleSwitch;
```

I also connected the switch with `toggleSwitch` outlet. Now I want to use this `toggleSwitch` field in my other view controller, how do I do that? Isn't using `@public` in the field declaration enough? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem at all. Just use the switch like this:

```
vcWhereYouDeclaredTheSwitch.toggleSwitch.on = YES;
```

or

```
BOOL test = [vcWhereYouDeclaredTheSwitch.toggleSwitch isOn];
```

inside your other view controller.

Here are some general thoughts about propertys:

- *Memory management* : Behind the scenes it will create a setter which creates the variable with correct  *memory management*. It will save you some headaches because you can easily see how the *memory management* is done (`strong`/`weak` and `retain`/`copy`/`assign`).
- *Accessibility from other classes*: if you declare your `@property` in the .h and `@synthesize` it in the .m you ivar will be public readable and writeable. You can prevent this with a privat class extension. You even can declare a `@property` public `readonly` and declare them internally `readwrite` via a privat class extension.
  Eg: a private property

```
   // [In the implementation file]  
   @interface MyClass ()  
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* someData; // private!!   
   @end  

   @implementation MyClass @synthesize someData   
   @end
```

- *Custom getter and setter*: If you like you can still write custom getter and setters and you can even just write a getter or setter and let the other one automatically `@synthesize`. And you can write custom logic into such a getter and setter e.g. you can reload a tableview after a `@property` has changed.
- *Automatic Key-Value-Observing (KVO) compliant*: If you use or planning to use KVO you get it basically for free by just declaring the property. Nothing else need to be done!
- If you need you iVar to be public it is simpler to write one `@property` than writing a getter and setter for a iVar
- With a `@property` you do not need to declare in iVar (in iOS and 64bit Mac Os X applications). You can do it via the `@synthesize`:

```
    @synthesize myiVar = _myIvar;
```

Comment: thanks! It worked fine but I checked if it still works without `@public` in the declaration of toggleSwitch and it did. Why? Is it simply because I'm importing that vc in other vc so it doesn't matter? And other thing, though it worked fine with the switch being ON by default but when I switched off the switch it threw an exception: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in the main.m file. I get this  error quite often while working with Xcode, this error is a real pain in my ass. Please help.

Comment: added some info about iVas and propertys - about your other error: it may be more useful if you make a new question out of it so everyone can help you and/or use the information later.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the property of UISwitch. So, you can use it anywhere by using the viewcontroller object.

Suppose you wanna use it in the view where you are currently then use it

self.toggleSwitch

// or

viewControllerObject.toggleSwitch

Comment: I see. Thanks. Another quick question-->though everything worked fine with the switch being ON by default but when I switched off the switch it threw an exception: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in the main.m file. I get this error quite often while working with Xcode, this error is a real pain in my ass. Please help

Comment: you must be passing some wrong parameters. Can you please share code where exactly you are using it